# Actual webpage looks good on IE browser but not on the online render tools. What am I missing here?

Tags: html, css

I have a ready template that is supposed to support the major browsers and IE versions 9, 10 and 11. The web page looks good on Chrome, Firefox and in my IE 10.
Using the F12 (developer tools) I have tested it using Browser Mode set at IE9, 8 and 7.

In the  I have added `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>` so the "Document Mode" is set to Standards by default. I have choosed `Edge` because it fixed some issues on 7 and 8, that were not fixed using the `content="IE=1E9"`.

So everything looks nice in my pc, supposing that the "Browser Mode" is actual how it looks on an installed IE9, 8, 7.

When I use some online tools like http://netrenderer.com/ and set my choice to IE8 it shows a messy site, not like the one I see.

Who is the correct? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Don't test using browser modes, use the actual browser - you can download free virtual machines from [modern.ie](http://modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads).

Settings the `IE=Edge` doesn't guarantee proper browser mode. Check in the VMs or using browserstack to make sure the browser modes are being set correctly in the F12 tools

Comment: Thank you for this, but isn't supposed that this is the job of delevoper tools of IE?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I have been mislead on more than one occasion using the IE developer tools when assuring my sites look good on IE variants. If you are familiar with VMs then I would suggest installing a Windows guest machine and install the appropriate browser versions.

If you want to test on your local machine for IE issues I use BrowserStack and I can configure it to run on my local machine so I can see my changes as I go along rather than making changes on local, publishing them, and then going into my VM and seeing if things look good.